# MariaDB: Can multiple clients use a single database

Tags: database, database-design, mariadb

First off, here's a quick look at the architecture:

- 1..n workstations running RHEL 7.2 on a closed network
- 1 NAS hosting the application and (.dat) data files
- Due to size, each workstation has its MariaDB database moved from the WS to the NAS, and each DB is in its NAS own directory

**Here are my questions**:  Can I have each WS use the same (a single) MariaDB database on the NAS? If so, what is the best way to set up the DB architecture; is pointing to a single, moved DB good enough or do I need to do something else?

It would greatly simplify things if all the workstations, which use the same application, could use (point to) the same database.

Thank you for any /all input.

Comment: How many instances of MariaDB?  If a single instance, how are clients distinguished?  (Eg, via a column `client_id`.)

Comment: Each WS has its own instance of MariaDB; so, that would be 1..n instances of MariaDB. I tried point WS2 to WS1's database (via the my.cnf file), but that didn't end well. There is no single MariaDB server.